# Golang struct array values not appending In loop

Tags: struct, go, append, slice

This is my code:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type Category struct {
    Id   int
    Name string
}

type Book struct {
    Id         int
    Name       string
    Categories []Category
}

func main() {
    var book Book

    book.Id = 1
    book.Name = "Vanaraj"

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        book.Categories = []Category{
            {
                Id : 10,
                Name : "Vanaraj",
            },
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(book)
}
```

I need to append the values to the categories. The values are appending only one time. But I need to append the values to the array.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 18):

You are not appending anything to `book.Categories`, in each iteration of the `for` loop you always create a new slice with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) and you assign it to `book.Categories`.

If you want to append values, use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    book.Categories = append(book.Categories, Category{
        Id:   10,
        Name: "Vanaraj",
    })
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/anWN5Y7KbE)):

```
{1 Vanaraj [{10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj} {10 Vanaraj}]}
```

Also note that if you know the iteration count in advance (`10` in your case), you can create a big-enough slice beforehand, you can use `for ... range` and just assign values to the proper element without calling `append()`. This is more efficient:

```
book.Categories = make([]Category, 10)
for i := range book.Categories {
    book.Categories[i] = Category{
        Id:   10,
        Name: "Vanaraj",
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty sir, i got the same problem and this solution solved